# Characteristics of layer only for overlapping area of another layer

Tags: layers, merge

I have got two layers, one with the land cover of Zimbabwe and another with the administrative divisions. I need to isolate a district and identify its land cover. I managed to cut out the district I need and make a new layer with it. However, every time I show the layer with the land cover, I get the land cover for the whole country. As, visually speaking, I only need that district, how can I do that? I tried to merge them or use "Union"/"Intersect", but all the land cover features disappear with these tools.